# branching practices when moving from SVN to TFS

Tags: svn, tfs

Our current setup is SVN, AnkhSVN, CCNET. I have read most of the SVN+TFS posts out here, and I still need some more information (this is not duplicate).

Our current setup is that we have 8 braches at any given time that are working on the same code base.

```
Main Trunk --> Project 1
Project 1--> Project 2
Project 1 --> Project 3 --> Project 4.
```

After we do our deployment, we merge back to the Main trunk, which is no small feat even using the best merge tools because of the way SVN does ancestry.

We have recently purchase TFS and it is my task to get the source control setup.

Would branching and merging be easier with TFS? While there is a lot of literature seeming to suggest that, I would like hear from people that are actually doing it.

Comment: As we have been unable to find a solution we are getting a consulting group to help us setup the source control part of it. I cannot seem to find how to merge between non-parent/child branches without doing a baseless merge. I will post the methodology that the group develops for us, maybe it will benefit someone else.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex.

Comment: Thanks Martin, how does it actually work..comparitively to SVN ?

Comment: It is a guide on how to branch and merge using TFS 2010.  I can't speak for your specific situation with SVN, so you will have to read it to see how it applies.